# Python Django: Sending a message from server to client on database save()

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels, django-signals

I want to notify the client when my model is saved.
I started by creating a django-signal on post_save.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Scooter)
async def scooter_post_update(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # Notify client here
```

Next I created the AsyncConsumer class from django-channels and provided its routing.

```
// routing.py
    application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
        # Empty for now (http->django views is added by default)
        'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(
                URLRouter(
                    [
                        path('scooters/', ScootersUpdateConsumer)
                    ]
               )
        )
    )
})

// consumers.py
    class ScootersUpdateConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
        async def websocket_connect(self, event):
            print("Connected!", event)
            await self.send({
                "type": "websocket.accept"
            })
        async def send_message(self):
            await self.send({
                "type": "websocket.send",
                'text': 'Oy, mate!'
            })
        async def websocket_receive(self, event):
            print("Receive!", event)
        async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
            print("Disconnected!", event)
```

Now my question is how can I call send_message() from the scooter_post_update() method.

Answer (score 3):

The steps are really straightforward. You have to get the channel layer and just send a message with `type` key set as your listening method name:

```py
    import channels
    from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

    @receiver(post_save, sender=Scooter)
    def scooter_post_update(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)(
            {"type": "send_message", "data": data}
        )
```

and any other stuff you want to send over channel.

Beware that all the data you pass **must** be serializable, so you have to take care that all your objects are serialized beforehand.

The mandatory part of the dictionary you pass to the `send` method is the `type` key (as mentioned before), which has to contain the method name which will be called on the consumer.

Moreover, you can use groups, so you can broadcast a message to a group of listeners:

```py
    import channels
    from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

    @receiver(post_save, sender=Scooter)
    def scooter_post_update(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            "group_name", {"type": "send_message", "data": data}
        )
```

and on the consumer side:

```py
    class ScootersUpdateConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
        async def websocket_connect(self, event):
            await self.channel_layer.group_add("group_name", self.channel_name)
            await self.send({
                "type": "websocket.accept"
            })
```

Note that in both cases, you use the `async_to_sync` wrapper which should be used when you call async code from sync scope.